# Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type '' while trying to migrate database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Asp.Net project where I try to migrate a Database with a DbContext.
Unfortunately, I get the Error

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Bulky.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Bulky.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

when I try to migrate the database with the

> dotnet ef migrations add AddCategoryToDbAndSeedTable

command

Can you explain to me why it's not working?
I attached the whole project with a google drive link

Project link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hEIv9BeocKmFZRyELYeUZTTtyrIaZbF9/view?usp=sharing

Edit:
And here are the verbose logs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPweHJc0YsI-Kg_5W6D5cfFQd3n6X8XU/view?usp=sharing

Here is the relevant code:

Program.cs:

```
using Bulky.DataAccess.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
            new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Action", DisplayOrder = 1 },
            new Category { Id = 2, Name = "SciFi", DisplayOrder = 2 },
            new Category { Id = 3, Name = "History", DisplayOrder = 3 }
            );
    }
```

Comment: From what folder do you run the command?

Comment: From the Bulky.DataAccess project

Comment: I can add the verbose logging as well

Comment: verbose logs added

Comment: I added relevant code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `--project` (the project to which the new EF migration should be added) and `--startup-project` (the project which contains the DB settings) to run the migration against.  Without these settings, the `Bulky.DataAccess` project does not have the DB connection string and the `ApplicationDbContext` cannot be constructed without dependency injection setup from the `BulkyWeb3` project.

**From the same folder as BuklyWeb3.sln**, you can run this command:

`dotnet ef migrations add AddInitialMigration --startup-project BulkyWeb3 --project Bulky.DataAccess`

Or, from the same folder as Bulky.DataAccess.csproj, you can run this command:

`dotnet ef migrations add AddInitialMigration --startup-project ..\BulkyWeb3`

These commands will create a new EF migration in the new `/BulkyWeb3/Bulky.DataAccess/Migrations` folder.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It works. Thank you!

Comment: No need to pass `--startup-project` in the first case. Also the project path is wrong it should be `--project ../Bulky.DataAccess`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` which will provice a connection string to your `ApplicationDbContext` while working with the `dotnet ef` cli tools.

The connection string can just point to localdb, since `dotnet ef migrations add` does not connect to the database, it just needs to be able to instantiate your `DbContext`.

```
public class ApplicationDesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=ApplicationDb;integrated security=true;");

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"What you need is an ..."_ - or does not =) Since correct project paths can be passed to the command.

Comment: Same goes for the other answer "You need ...". Doing either one works. Depends if op want to modify the code once or always specify extra command args.